# Lights and shade with a custom fragmentShader

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm creating a sphere and adding distortion to it, that's working fine.
When I look at the wireframe it's like this

[image: wireframe]

and with the wireframe turned of it looks like this

[image: solid]

As you can see the are no shades and the distortion isn't visible when the wireframe is turned of.

What I'm looking for is what to place in my custom fragmentShader.

I used this

```
        // calc the dot product and clamp
        // 0 -> 1 rather than -1 -> 1
        vec3 light = vec3(0.5,0.2,1.0);

        // ensure it's normalized
        light = normalize(light);

        // calculate the dot product of
        // the light to the vertex normal
        float dProd = max(0.0, dot(vNormal, light));

        // feed into our frag colour
        gl_FragColor = vec4(dProd, dProd, dProd, 1.0);
```

But that just creates a very ugly false light.
Any ideas anybody?

Thanks in advance,
Wezy

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Three.js' lights (and I can't think a reason why not), you need to include the corresponding shader chunks:

1. Take a look at how the WebGLRenderer [composes its shaders in THREE.ShaderLib](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/WebGLShaders.js#L1952)
2. Pick a material there that is close to what you want and copy its definition (uniforms and both shader codes) to your code, renaming it to something custom
3. Delete chunks you don't need, and add your custom code to appropriate places

Comment: So I'm trying to add chunks but I don't get it to work. How can I add these chunks, are there any examples on how to add these chuncks because I can't find them